# In the build.gradle, what are the differences between the compile and cordacompile

Tags: corda

in the build.gradle file, you have a list of dependencies which you need to run he Corda node, are there documentations on each of the different functions associated with the packages? Right now there are

```
dependencies {
      compile ...
      testCompile ...

      cordaCompile ...
      cordaRuntime ... 

}
```

What are the differences (in particular to the compile vs cordaCompile)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html#corda-dependencies)

The cordformation and cordapp plugins add two new gradle configurations:

- `cordaCompile` which extends `compile`
- `cordaRuntime` which extends `runtime`

`cordaCompile` and `cordaRuntime` indicate dependencies that should *not* be included in the CorDapp JAR.

These configurations should be used for any Corda dependency (e.g. corda-core, corda-node) in order to prevent a dependency from being included twice (once in the CorDapp JAR and once in the Corda JARs).

The `cordapp` plugin should be applied to any project that will be building a cordapp

and the `cordformation` plugin should be applied to projects that wish to create small testing networks locally.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `Compile` and `CordaCompile` is with `CordaCompile` you're indicating which dependencies you *don't* want to be included in the CorDapp jar.
This is to prevent dependencies from being included twice (the other being in the Corda.jar)

`CordaRuntime` does the same thing as `CordaCompile` but also indicates it as a runtime dependency.

`TestCompile` indicates dependencies only required for running tests.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. For example in the corda-training-solutions, we have the following: // Corda integration dependencies
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-rpc:$corda_release_version"
    cordaCompile "net.corda:corda-node-api:$corda_release_version"

Are you saying we don't need these?

Comment: How about the testcompile and cordaRuntime?

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't need those in the CorDapp jar.
See edited answer