# Corda - There is more than one CorDapp containing the package

Tags: kotlin, corda

I am building an application that requires multiple CorDapps; let's call them **LibCorDapp** and **AppCorDapp**, where **AppCorDapp** depends on **LibCorDapp** (Just like a CorDapp may depend on the Accounts or Tokens SDK).

### LibCorDapp - Contract

The purpose of this CorDapp is to define an object model of states and contracts that can be used out of the box, but can also be derived from to create more explicit state and contract types.

**build.gradle**

```
cordapp {
    targetPlatformVersion cordapp_platform_version
    minimumPlatformVersion cordapp_platform_version
    contract {
        name cordapp_contract_name
        vendor cordapp_vendor_name
        licence cordapp_license
        versionId cordapp_version_id
    }
    signing {
        enabled = cordapp_signing_enabled
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "$kotlin_group:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"

    testRuntimeOnly "$junit_group:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "$junit_group:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "$kotlin_group:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "$corda_group:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"
}
```

**Example State**

```kotlin
package com.example.libcordapp.contract

@BelongsToContract(ExampleContract::class)
open class ExampleState<T : Any>(
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = emptyList(),
    val value: T
) : ContractState { ... }
```

**Example Contract**

```kotlin
package com.example.libcordapp.contract

open class ExampleContract {
    final override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) { ... }
    protected open fun onVerifyCreate(tx: LedgerTransaction, signers: Set<PublicKey>) = Unit
}
```

Note the relationship between `ExampleState` and `ExampleContract`. They're both `open`, and `ExampleContract` contains an overridable function to allow deriving classes to specify additional contract logic on creation.

### LibCorDapp - Workflow

The purpose of this CorDapp is to define the flows that allow example states to be created, updated and consumed. These flows *should* also work with states and contracts that derive from `ExampleState` and `ExampleContract`.

**build.gradle**

```
cordapp {
    targetPlatformVersion cordapp_platform_version
    minimumPlatformVersion cordapp_platform_version
    workflow {
        name cordapp_workflow_name
        vendor cordapp_vendor_name
        licence cordapp_license
        versionId cordapp_version_id
    }
    signing {
        enabled = cordapp_signing_enabled
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "$kotlin_group:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordapp project(":libcordapp-contract")

    testRuntimeOnly "$junit_group:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "$junit_group:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "$kotlin_group:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "$corda_group:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"
}
```

**Example Flow**

```kotlin
package com.example.libcordapp.workflow

class ExampleFlow(val state: ExampleState) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() { 
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val tx = with(TransactionBuilder(notary)) {
            addOutputState(state)
            addCommand(ExampleContract.Issue, signers)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I haven't explicitly defined the contract ID for the output state, because it should be determined at runtime for each contract/state pair.

### AppCorDapp - Contract

The purpose of this CorDapp is to demonstrate an example of an application consuming **LibCorDapp**, creating and testing derived states and contracts.

**build.gradle**

```
cordapp {
    targetPlatformVersion cordapp_platform_version
    minimumPlatformVersion cordapp_platform_version
    contract {
        name "Test CorDapp Contract"
        vendor cordapp_vendor_name
        licence cordapp_license
        versionId cordapp_version_id
    }
    signing {
        enabled = cordapp_signing_enabled
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "$kotlin_group:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "$corda_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordapp project(":libcordapp-contract")

    testRuntimeOnly "$junit_group:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "$junit_group:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "$kotlin_group:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "$corda_group:corda-node-driver:$corda_release_version"
}
```

**GreetingState**

```kotlin
package com.example.appcordapp.contract

@BelongsToContract(GreetingContract::class)
class GreetingState(
    participants: List<AbstractParty> = emptyList()
    value: String = "Hello, World!"
) : ExampleState<String>(participants, value)
```

**Greeting Contract**

```kotlin
package com.example.appcordapp.contract

class GreetingContract : ExampleContract {
    override fun onVerifyCreate(tx: LedgerTransaction, signers: Set<PublicKey>) = requireThat { ... }
}
```

Note that `GreetingContract` extends `ExampleContract` and `GreetingState` extends `ExampleState` as well as defining `GreetingContract` as it's related contract, so when creating a `GreetingState` using `ExampleFlow` it should pick up this contract.

*There are actually no flows defined in the **AppCorDapp - Workflow** module because I explicitly want to test that I can use `ExampleFlow` with my derived state/contract pair.*

### Testing & Problem

For my tests I've defined the following cordapps:

```kotlin
cordappsForAllNodes = listOf(
    TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.example.libcordapp.contract"),
    TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.example.libcordapp.workflow"),
    TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.example.appcordapp.contract")
)
```

Upon trying to create a `GreetingState` using `ExampleFlow`...

```kotlin
ExampleFlow(GreetingState(participants = listOf(partyA)))
```

...I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is more than one CorDapp containing the package com.example.appcordapp.contract on the classpath [/.../libcordapp-contract-0.1.jar, /.../libcordapp-workflow-0.1.jar]. Specify a package name which is unique to the CorDapp.

I'm assuming this is either down to gradle or something to do with the fact that I'm using derived states and contracts?

Comment: I think  derived contracts  is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the official documentation about [dependencies](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/cordapp-build-systems.html#corda-dependencies), and reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523275/11809424); I suggest that you change `cordapp project(":libcordapp-contract")` inside `build.gradle` of `AppCorDapp - Contract` to `cordaCompile project(":libcordapp-contract")`.

In your current dependency setup (i.e. using `cordapp`), `libcordapp-contract` is getting included in the jar file of your CorDapp, so when you are running your test, the package is found in 2 places: `LibCorDapp - Contract` and `AppCorDapp - Contract` CorDapps; if you change the dependency to `cordaCompile`, the package will only be included in the jar file of `LibCorDapp - Contract` CorDapp.

Comment: Sadly, I get the same results with `cordaCompile` :(

Comment: What happens if you remove `TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.example.libcordapp.contract")`? I mean since `libcordapp-contract` already exists in `TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.example.appcordapp.contract")`; you should be able to run your tests with just the latter.